# How to safely use QQmlEngine::CppOwnership?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

When calling C++ from QML, a `QObject` can be returned to qml by pointer. Before returning, I can call

```
QObject* qobj = m_sharedPtr.data(); // Pointer to member shared-ptr-managed object.
QQmlEngine::setObjectOwnership(qobj, QQmlEngine::CppOwnership);
return qobj;
```

but given that QML is garbage-collected, how can this work safely? My mental model is that QML will get the pointer and hold onto it, wrapped in some QML pointer wrapper and that pointer wrapper will eventually be GC'd. But then there's no limit to how long after the `setObjectOwnership` call that QML could access `*qobj`. (E.g., perhaps the next QML->C++ call after this one causes `m_sharedPtr` to go out of scope.) Does that mean `QQmlEngine::CppOwnership` is only safe to use when the object's lifetime is essentially infinite (e.g., a singleton)? I don't see any alternative, but haven't found any mention of this issue in any documentation.

Comment: When you set `QQmlEngine::CppOwnership` it's not garbage collected any more. Simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

If `m_sharedPtr` refers to data created in C++, `qobj` will have `CppOwnership` anyways, and you should handle it like any other C++ smart pointer (i.e. let it live as long as you actually need it).

If it was created in QML, it will have `JavaScriptOwnership` by default. If you then transfer ownership to C++, and it gets destroyed, it's not accessible in QML anymore.

If it is important that `qobj` is accessible in QML for an uncertain time, but still C++-managed, you could retreat to using raw pointers and handle the destruction yourself (e.g. by connecting to the `aboutToClose()` signal of a QML window).

Comment: The case I'm most concerned with is if `qobj` is returned from a C++ class that owns it but that may change at any time. For example, the C++ class could cache a most-recent result and that's what `qobj` is. It seems like QML could ask for the result, get it, then another thread causes `*qobj` to be deleted, then QML goes to inspect `*qobj` and we have undefined behavior, even if QML is "just" asking for a value momentarily as in `if (cpp.getQObj().isValid())`. Jus tbecause `cpp.getQObj()` returns a valid `qobj` doesn't mean it's still there when `.isValid()` is called. Right?

Comment: @Ben With `CppOwnership` you are taking responsibility to keep that object valid, just as you do with regular C++ code. If you don't mess up ownership, then you are safe. But if you pass some pointers, delete pointed objects and create danglingpointers, then sorry...

Comment: Right. My question, then, is if I've shown QML an object with `CppOwnership`, how can I possibly know when it would be safe to delete the object?

Comment: You could connect to the `destroyed` Signal of your `QObject` and then either delete the object or have some kind of logic to let whatever is managing the object know that it’s safe to delete it. 


`connect(qobj, &QObject::destroyed, this, &Class::deleteData)`